# SQL Server Standard Edition Failover Cluster Installing Windows Updates

Tags: sql-server, clustering, failover

i have a question concerning the installation of sql server updates on a sql server 2012 standard edition failover cluster.

For example a service pack installation. Is it possible to install the service pack at first on one node? And after the sucessfull installtion do the same thing on the other node? So that i have no downtime for the applications during the restart?

Greetings

Comment: It seems like this is possible. [Upgrade a SQL Server Failover Cluster Instance (Setup)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191295(v=sql.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is how we need to roll out patches in the sql cluster with minimum downtime. The downtime will be during the failover part.

Process:

1. Patch the passive node first.
2. Move the resources to the passive node.(This will become active now)
3. Patch the current passive node.(It was originally active).

Before doing this do test it in a Test environment and prepare a full proof plan.

Also refer to this link :

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/john_daskalakis/2014/09/05/how-to-install-a-service-pack-at-a-sql-server-2012-failover-instance-best-practices/

Comment: There will be some short downtime during the failover.

Comment: Yup, this is the best practise for a minimum downtime which will during the failover.